# Play video in a div in HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to play a video in a div tag in html 
but when I used the following code, the browser asked if I want to download the video. I do not want to download it, I just want to play it. Also this message appeared in the div

> "You need to install an extension to view this content"

I'm using firefox browser

This what I used in html file :

```
<div>
<object type="Brave/quicktime" data="Brave.avi" width="624" height="352">
<param name="pluginurl" value="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" />
<param name="controller" value="false" />
<param name="autoplay" value="true" />
</object>
</div>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using HTML5's `<video>` tag?

Comment: @ JulesMazur
I tried and the browser gave me this message
Did not find the video format or type MIME

Comment: Which browser (version and build) are you using?

Comment: @JulesMazur 
I'm usinf firefox 18.0.1

Comment: That's odd. According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Cvideo%3E), FF has supported `<video>` since 16.0. Could it have anything to do with the type being `"Brave/quicktime"`? `Brave` isn't a format I've heard of. EDIT: `"Brave/quicktime"` isn't a valid type. It should be `video/quicktime`. EDIT2: the `quicktime` type is reserved for .mov files. This should be `video/avi`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the video tag

```
 <div>
   <video width="700" height="450" controls="controls" poster="image" preload="true">
     <source src="where the video is" type="video/mov"/>
     <source src="where the video is" type="video/mp4" />
     <source src="where the video is" type="video/oog" />
     Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video>
</div>
```

You also need to use a different video type. AVI file types are not supported in the html5 video tag.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<video width="624" height="352" controls>
<source src="Brave.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Also i wouldn't use AVI as the format for the video.

Use MP4 then you can use the HTML5 video tag.

Comment: the browser gave me this message :
Did not find the video format or type MIME

Comment: This will only work if you have a .mp4 version of the video file in the directory.

Comment: I tied ti use .mp4 vedio but the browser give this message 
"quick time has collapsed"

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you're using an invalid MIME type (as you've pointed out yourself, the browser returns an "invalid MIME type" message). You're also using the `<object>` tag, which is deprecated as of HTML5.

Before using up-to-date markup, make sure your `DOCTYPE` declaration reads, `<DOCTYPE html>`, and nothing more. This tells the browser that you're using an HTML5 document, and that the proper tag definitions should be loaded. If you declare an HTML4 `DOCTYPE`, your browser might not be able to process HTML5 tags.

Once that's done, use the `<video>` tag. Now, your markup should look something like this:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- your styles, scripts, and other head info -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <video src="Brave.avi" controls="yourControls" autoplay="false">
        Your browser doesn't support the `<video>` tag. /*this is a fallback*/
        </video>
    </body>
<html>
```

You'll notice that there's no `type` attribute for the `<video>` tag. That's because *[the `<video>` tag doesn't actually support that attribute](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video)*. This makes for less coding, which is always a good thing.

On a side note, avoid using the `.avi` format. The h264 codec just became an official standard, which means that using `.mp4`, or even the oft-neglected `.ogg` format are preferable, as they use less bandwidth, and are more widely supported.

Comment: The solution that works is that in your previous comment which is using object tag and modify "Brave/quicktime" to "vedio/quicktime"

Comment: the browser gave me the same message for this solution